# Calculating amount of alkali additions to get desired pH in (hard) cider

Tags: acid-base, food-chemistry, mole, applied-chemistry

This is linked to my question over on the HomeBrew SE site: https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/18837/reduce-acidity-of-hard-cider

I haven't done chemistry since I was 17/18 but I remember doing molar calculations and so on, and the principle of OH ions binding with H ions to reduce acidity. I would prefer a more scientific method than trial and error.

Given an initial pH, desired pH and volume of liquid, how can I calculate the mass of a given salt to add... and is it as simple as that or are there more 'parameters' needed to generate some equations?

The salts I am likely to consider using are:

- sodium bicarbonate (sodium hydrogen carbonate?)
- magnesium carbonate
- calcium carbonate
- potassium carbonate

Is it as simple as working out how many moles of OH each of these contains per gram, and plugging that into a pH equation?